# Sifr text not resizing when you zoom in with the browser (command + or -)

Tags: sifr

If you re-size or re-scale your browser window on the following site that I'm working on the sifr fonts do not change size at all. And even worse if the page is sized down some of the sifr text will get cut off on the edges.
http://hokey.squarespace.com/
I'm guessing it's an easy fix. I'm kinda new to sifr. 
Please help if someone can!

Answer (score 1):

sIFR 3 does this properly.